# Access One to One Relationship Table

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to build several tables based on one single table(parent table) : the idea is that the first 3 columns of all the child tables will be the same as the parent table and each child table has a few more information provided.  Whatever change made in the parent table will reflect in the child table. For example, if previous one row in the parent table is harry True Happy is changed to Harry True Sad, the child tables will also be changed . Also if a record in the parent table is deleted, the corresponding rows in the child tables will also be deleted.  A new record in the parent table is created, the child table will also generate one row of record reflecting the update.

I think the one-to-one relationship in Access will be a good way to achieve that. Will that be feasible as I don't have much theoretical understanding about the database.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is exactly how relationships should work, so that you won't have to repeat the 3 columns on each related table.

```
Parent
ID(PrimaryKey)  C1  C2  C3

Child1
ID(PrimaryKey) C4 C5

Child2
ID(PrimaryKey) C6 C7
```

As for the deletion, there is the option of `CASCADE DELETE` exactly for your purposes, if you check the `Enforce Referencial Integrity` box.

However whether the relationships are gonna be 1-to-1 or 1-to-N, largely depends on the database you are building.

If it's a 1-to-1, the Primary Keys should be the same, for the same records. Otherwise you should include a `RelatedParentId (ForeignKey)` field in your child tables.

[image: Table View Mode]
[image: Relationship]

Comment: Hello, I tested both update and delete synchronization can be done through this. However, will it be possible that when we create one record in the parent table, it automatically generate one more row in the child tables(the rest of the columns are left empty)? In short, I would like the shared columns in parent and child tables be exactly the same no matter what.

Comment: Using relationships, there are actually no shared columns. In a 1-to-1 relationship, if you create a record in one table, you will see a (+) button on its left, allowing you to add data to the other table. See my edited answer for the picture. Generally access supports these relationships in many ways, i.e. the Master-Child linked forms.